# soulmate.js - Caution: Provisional headers are shown in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, autocomplete

I am using [soulmate.js](https://github.com/mcrowe/soulmate.js) a jQuery Front-end to the Soulmate Auto-suggestion Gem in my rails application to provide an autosuggest system. The autocompletion works perfectly on development but on production it fails.

On inspecting the requests on chrome, the requests fail and no results are returned

[image: provisional headers are shown and no results return]

Testing on mozilla, firebug also shows that all requests failed

[image: firebug failed requests]

I have this in my js

```
(function() {
  var render, select, link;
  $('#search-input').focus();
  render = function(term, data, type) {
    return term;
  };
  select = function(term, data, type) {
    $('#search-input').val(term);
    $('ul#soulmate').hide();
    return window.location = data.permalink;
  };

  $('#search-input').soulmate({
    url: '/autocomplete/search',
    types: ['movies','shows'],
    renderCallback: render,
    selectCallback: select,
    minQueryLength: 2,
    maxResults: 12
  });
}).call(this);
```

Like I said this works perfectly on localhost but not in production. I've searched around and nothing works. What could be the problem? Any suggestions on how to fix this are highly appreciated.

Comment: I have not used soulmate but I've seen similar `Abort` messages with autocomplete funcationality, usually if you type a few letter it fires the auto complete server call and then you type a few more it aborts the original request - but in my case it did not abort the last call? I was using this technique: http://railscasts.com/episodes/399-autocomplete-search-terms